# WSO2 Carbon Database getting corrupted

Tags: wso2

Whenever we deploy an API Manager and users create accounts, after some time - weeks, days and sometimes in a matter of minutes - the carbon database seems to get corrupt and users are no longer able to sign in or even create accounts. The error that arrises is

`WARN - AuthenticationHandler Illegal access attempt at [2013-05-19 13:13:37,0963] from IP address 192.168.0.5 while trying to authenticate access to service UserAdmin`

The only option we have is to recreate the database and redefine the services which is quite laborious and time consuming.

Any ideas?

Comment: We haven't faced such issue.. Waht is the version of APIM you are using? Is it a distributed setup or single instance setup? Are you using default setup fro userstore or customized userstore? How you are creating users?

Comment: The APIM is running on a single VM so it's a single instance setup. The issue seems to be the DataBase because when I switch it out with a fresh database then the application works fine. Users are being created on the front end of the store.

Comment: if users are created from store end, they have subscriber+login permission only..Did you try to login to publisher/gateway? OR you are trying to login from store and facing this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This error comes when you have changed the admin user password. If you have changed it make sure to update APIM_HOME/repository/conf/api-manager.xml with new admin passwords for following configurations.

AuthManager

APIGateway

APIKeyManager