# WSO2IOT Error after changing admin password wso2iot

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I changed the admin password in WSO2IOT 3.0.0 and I got an error after rebooting the wso2iot server. The error happens only after changing the admin password, with admin/admin everything is working fine.

I tried to change the password in the file and via the web interface but can't make it works. I've followed this tutorial : https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS300/Changing+the+Super+Administrator+Password

And I tried a lot of times to reboot the server, in the order first broker then core and analytics.

I tried to change the admin password in every file of wso with this script :

```
#!/bin/bash


find /home/wso/wso2iot-3.0.0/wso2iot-3.0.0 -iname "*" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -i -H "password\">admin" 2>/dev/null > /home/mdp.txt
cat /home/mdp.txt |grep -v -i "dossier\|tmp\|xmle*" > /home/mdpch.txt
cat /home/mdpch.txt

find /home/wso/wso2iot-3.0.0/wso2iot-3.0.0 -name "*.xml" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -ie 's/<property name=\"password\">admin<\/property>/<property name=\"password\">mynewpassword!<\/property>/g'
find /home/wso/wso2iot-3.0.0/wso2iot-3.0.0 -name "*.xml" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -ie 's/<Property Name=\"password\">admin<\/Property>/<Property Name=\"password\">mynewpassword!<\/Property>/g'
find /home/wso/wso2iot-3.0.0/wso2iot-3.0.0 -name "*.xml" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -ie 's/<property key=\"password\">admin<\/property>/<property key=\"password\">mynewpassword!<\/property>/g'
```

When i want to go on https://IP:9443/devicemgt I got the error :

```
An Error Occurred!
HTTP Status : 500

{/app/modules/oauth/token-handlers.js} Could not set up encoded tenant based client credentials to session context as the server is unable to obtain such credentials - setUpEncodedTenantBasedClientAppCredentials(x)
```

In the wso file : 
Here is the error I got :
In core/bin/wso2server.sh

```
[2017-04-10 15:19:14,649] [IoT-Core]  WARN - CarbonAuthenticationUtil Failed Administrator login attempt 'admin[-1234]' at [2017-04-10 15:19:14,649+0200]
[2017-04-10 15:19:14,650] [IoT-Core]  WARN - AuthenticationHandler Illegal access attempt at [2017-04-10 15:19:14,0650] from IP address IPAddressOfServer while trying to authenticate access to service APIKeyMgtSubscriberService
[2017-04-10 15:19:14,652] [IoT-Core] ERROR - AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl Can not retrieve OAuth application for the given consumer key : 0PPTv__wTIzmffXH72cogAghm0wa
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Access Denied. Authentication failed - Invalid credentials provided.
        at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:370)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:445)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.retrieveOAuthApplication(APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.java:1683)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.client.SubscriberKeyMgtClient.getOAuthApplication(SubscriberKeyMgtClient.java:89)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.retrieveApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:237)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.getClientOfApplication(ApiMgtDAO.java:2439)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.getOAuthApplications(ApiMgtDAO.java:2403)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.getApplications(ApiMgtDAO.java:4700)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.getApplications(APIConsumerImpl.java:3135)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIConsumer.getApplications(UserAwareAPIConsumer.java:36)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.application.extension.APIManagementProviderServiceImpl.generateAndRetrieveApplicationKeys(APIManagementProviderServiceImpl.java:136)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.application.extension.api.ApiApplicationRegistrationServiceImpl.register(ApiApplicationRegistrationServiceImpl.java:66)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:188)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:204)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:289)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:209)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:265)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.application.extension.api.filter.ApiPermissionFilter.doFilter(ApiPermissionFilter.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.authenticator.framework.WebappAuthenticationValve.processRequest(WebappAuthenticationValve.java:138)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.authenticator.framework.WebappAuthenticationValve.invoke(WebappAuthenticationValve.java:68)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2017-04-10 15:19:14,655] [IoT-Core] ERROR - ApiApplicationRegistrationServiceImpl Error occurred while registering an application 'webapp_carbon.super'
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.application.extension.exception.APIManagerException: Failed to register a api application : webapp_carbon.super
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.application.extension.APIManagementProviderServiceImpl.generateAndRetrieveApplicationKeys(APIManagementProviderServiceImpl.java:177)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.application.extension.api.ApiApplicationRegistrationServiceImpl.register(ApiApplicationRegistrationServiceImpl.java:66)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:188)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:204)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:289)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:209)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:265)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.application.extension.api.filter.ApiPermissionFilter.doFilter(ApiPermissionFilter.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.authenticator.framework.WebappAuthenticationValve.processRequest(WebappAuthenticationValve.java:138)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.authenticator.framework.WebappAuthenticationValve.invoke(WebappAuthenticationValve.java:68)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:958)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:452)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1087)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1756)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1715)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Can not retrieve OAuth application for the given consumer key : 0PPTv__wTIzmffXH72cogAghm0wa
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.handleException(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:639)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.retrieveApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:266)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.getClientOfApplication(ApiMgtDAO.java:2439)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.getOAuthApplications(ApiMgtDAO.java:2403)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.dao.ApiMgtDAO.getApplications(ApiMgtDAO.java:4700)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.getApplications(APIConsumerImpl.java:3135)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIConsumer.getApplications(UserAwareAPIConsumer.java:36)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.application.extension.APIManagementProviderServiceImpl.generateAndRetrieveApplicationKeys(APIManagementProviderServiceImpl.java:136)
        ... 54 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Access Denied. Authentication failed - Invalid credentials provided.
        at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:370)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:445)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.retrieveOAuthApplication(APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.java:1683)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.client.SubscriberKeyMgtClient.getOAuthApplication(SubscriberKeyMgtClient.java:89)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.retrieveApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:237)
        ... 60 more
[2017-04-10 15:19:14,674] [IoT-Core] ERROR - js {/app/modules/oauth/token-handler-utils.js} Error in retrieving tenant based client application credentials from API Manager - getTenantBasedClientAppCredentials(x, y)
[2017-04-10 15:19:14,674] [IoT-Core] ERROR - auth-module An exception thrown when executing the script '/app/modules/login.js'.
[2017-04-10 15:19:14,675] [IoT-Core] ERROR - auth-module {/app/modules/oauth/token-handlers.js} Could not set up encoded tenant based client credentials to session context as the server is unable to obtain such credentials - setUpEncodedTenantBasedClientAppCredentials(x)
[2017-04-10 15:19:15,848] [IoT-Core]  WARN - CarbonAuthenticationUtil Failed Administrator login attempt 'admin[-1234]' at [2017-04-10 15:19:15,848+0200]
[2017-04-10 15:19:15,849] [IoT-Core]  WARN - AuthenticationHandler Illegal access attempt at [2017-04-10 15:19:15,0849] from IP address IPAddressOfServer while trying to authenticate access to service APIKeyValidationService
[2017-04-10 15:19:15,854] [IoT-Core]  WARN - APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication failure due to Unclassified Authentication Failure
[2017-04-10 15:19:15,963] [IoT-Core]  WARN - CarbonAuthenticationUtil Failed Administrator login attempt 'admin[-1234]' at [2017-04-10 15:19:15,963+0200]
[2017-04-10 15:19:15,964] [IoT-Core]  WARN - AuthenticationHandler Illegal access attempt at [2017-04-10 15:19:15,0964] from IP address IPAddressOfServer while trying to authenticate access to service APIKeyValidationService
[2017-04-10 15:19:15,968] [IoT-Core]  WARN - APIAuthenticationHandler API authentication failure due to Unclassified Authentication Failure

[2017-04-10 15:19:51,052] [IoT-Core] ERROR - BasicAuthenticationInterceptor Authentication failed. Please check your username/password
```

In analytics/bin/wso2server.sh :

```
[2017-04-10 15:16:40,768] [IoT-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT Exception occurred when starting listener
Nom d'utilisateur ou mot de passe incorrect (4)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:28)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientState.notifyReceivedAck(ClientState.java:885)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:118)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I got same error, and found this link:
[WSO2 Carbon Database getting corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634075/wso2-carbon-database-getting-corrupted)

I changed all ${admin.password} entries to my new password in the file core/repository/conf/api-manager.xml and login started to work.

Also there is one official solution at the page https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS300/Changing+the+Super+Administrator+Password : *Changing the password via the device management console* .
It didn't work for me.

UPDATED. Actually you should use the second official way. https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS300/Changing+the+Super+Administrator+Password : **Changing the password via file configurations**.